# A question on arcwised connected spaces

Tags: general-topology

As the tite explains, how to prove that a arcwised connected space is connected space?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is arc-wise the same as path-connected?

Comment: I don't know;((

Comment: @MattN. Some authors make a subtle distinction: A path is a continuous map from the unit interval to the space and an arc is required to be a homeomorphism onto its image. Path-connected and arc-connected spaces are defined accordingly. For $T_2$-spaces these definitions are equivalent (one direction uses the [Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn.E2.80.93Mazurkiewicz_theorem)). In general they are distinct: A segment with two origins is an example of a path-connected space which is not arc-connected: there's no arc from one origin to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $X$ be a pathconnected space. Suppose $X$ is not connected. Then $X=X_1\sqcup X_2$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are non empty disjoint open subsets of $X$. Now take a point $x_1\in X_1$ and $x_2\in X_2$ then there is no way to join these two points by a continuous path, which contradicts the pathconnectedness hyposthesis of $X$.